# InDesign: Reset "Character Color" to default

Tags: adobe-indesign, color

Is it possible to reset character color to default? I had 70% tint of [Black]

[image: 70% tint of Black]

and now want it would be like this:

[image: Default character color]

How can it be done without creating a new style? I can change tint to 100%, but is it what InDesign uses by default? By default it shows no tint and question mark in the color square.

Comment: Many settings and preferences are kept with the document which has focus. If there is no document open, then many of the settings can be set for "all documents." But they may be overridden by currently open document afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTRL-Clicking the line with the color that is currently used has changed it to default state.